# What is the correct Lewis structure of difluorophosphate?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, lewis-structure, pnictogen

I can draw two possible Lewis structures for $\ce{PO2F2-}$ anion:

[image: Lewis structures of difluorophosphate]

What is the correct structure and why is the other one wrong?

Comment: I would prefer one with plus on P and minus on each O (if the matter were of any significance, that is).

Comment: @lvan but wouldn't the increased amount of charges in a molecule would make it unstable ( - repells- )

Comment: If anything, given that O is much more electronegative than P, my structure is slightly _more realistic_ in terms of charge distribution. Also, it correctly reflects the fact that both O atoms are identical.

Comment: @ivan neretin there’s a difference between the most accurate representation of the molecule and the conventional Lewis structure. Lewis structure conventions prioritize minimal formal charge over adherence to octet rule for third row elements (but the reverse for second row). I

Comment: @Andrew so in your opinion what is the correct structure in above Lewis structures?

Comment: Definitely structure 2